# Julia parallel file processing

Tags: file, parallel-processing, julia

I'm relatively new to Julia language, and I 've been recently trying to process some files in parallel manner. My code looks something like>

```
for ln in eachline (somefile)
...
proces this line

    for ln2 in eachline (someotherfile)
..
..
    process ln and ln2
..
..
```

I've been trying to speed things up a bit with @everywhere and @parallel functions, but it doesn't seem to work for eachline function.

Am I missing something?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `@parallel` macro we already know that:

```
@parallel [reducer] for var = range
   body
end
```

> The specified **range** is **partitioned** and locally executed across all workers.

To do the above job in minimum time, `@parallel` gets `length(range)` then partitions it between `nworkers()`.

for more details you can:
 . see macro output -> `macroexpand(:(@parallel for i in 1:5 i end))`
or:
 . check macro source -> [milti.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/1f392db7eed47e3161f6b4856dbcb9504cd9cf3b/base/multi.jl#L1647)

`EachLine` is one of Julia iterables, it implements all [mandatory methods](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/collections/#collections-and-data-structures) of iterable interface, but `length()` is not one of those. ([check this discussion](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/13772)), so `EachLine` is not a range and `@parallel` fails to do it's task because lack of `length()` function.

But there are at list two solutions to parallelize the **process part**:

1. use `lis=readlines()` to collect a range of lines, the `@parallel for li in lis`
2. use `pmap()`

> Julia’s **pmap()** (page 483) is designed for the case where each function
>   call does a large amount of work. In contrast, **@parallel** for can
>   handle situations where each iteration is tiny, perhaps merely summing
>   two numbers.

a sample code:

```
len=function(s::AbstractString)
      string(length(s)) * " " * string(myid());
    end
function test()
  open("eula.1028.txt") do io
    pmap(len,eachline(io))
  end
end
```